# "Serve static assets with an efficient cache policy" - How many days is best practice?

Tags: browser-cache, pagespeed, google-pagespeed

On google page speed test, it logically suggests to setup browser caching for static content, like .js .css etc.

*"A long cache lifetime can speed up repeat visits to your page."*

I am setting this up, but for how long?  There must be best practice on this, as I don't know if 7 days or 77 days is a good idea.  Perhaps subjective, site dependent and all that usual stuff, so is the longer the better?  A year perhaps?

I have cache busting enabled, so future updates aren't an issue for my website.

Comment: You can get the hint for resource caching time from Google Analytics. If your content doesn't change frequently and are getting high returning users and if they are only converting in sales, then it is a good idea to keep atleast 30 days time for caching. On the other hand, if content on your site updates frequently (like media sites) and your goal is to get only new users, then resource caching time could be 7 days or 14 days. Nowadays, users clear their browser cache atleast once in a month, so there isnt any practical advantage to keep longer time.

Comment: What kind of pseudo magic is this anyway. There should be an EXACT number answer to this question. 
Per my tests, the only thing that made it happy were values over 31 days. 
First off, that's ridiculous. Second off, why all the hidden information.
This tool is literally MADE for fake seo companies to generate work for themselves. Infuriating. Also, how come the score is totally different on Lighthouse, and how come the score changes everytime you run the tool? 
This whole "insights" scan is bogus.